# Running other C# code from inside my program

Tags: c#, debugging, command-line, execution

I am trying to make something like a command line for a game that I am developing using C#.
I would like to have something like:

```
string code;
code = Console.ReadLine();
Something.RunCode(code);
```

Where I can input a C# code snippet that interacts with things happening to the current thread of execution in my program (for example if I'm stuck in an infinite loop in the main program I can pull up the command line in a separate thread and type in "break;" or "MainThread.Abort();" and I can get out). I want to be able to use C# command line to interact with my program while it it running. I don't know if this is even possible, but I think it will really help me with debugging and such (like use the command line to make a part of my program throw an error and see how it handles it, without having to stop the program, add the error into the source code, and re-build). 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give example of code variable content?

Comment: You may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944036/compile-c-sharp-code-in-the-application

Comment: C# code is a [compiled language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language). It cannot just be run, like javascript wich is an [Interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language). So you need to compile this into something runnable before you can let it do anything

Comment: also this is seriously dangerous.

Comment: There's also [scriptcs](http://scriptcs.net/), which is very much like what you describe: A proper C# REPL.

Comment: Check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278251/dynamically-changing-conditions-of-an-if-statement-in-c-sharp/18854045#18854045

Comment: Thank you all for the great responses. I am not concerned about the safety of the code, as I am the only one who will be using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile an assembly on the fly

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.CompilerOptions = "/target:library";

compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
compilerParams.IncludeDebugInformation = false;

compilerParams.OutputAssembly = outTempPath;

CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, sourceCode);
```

You should sandbox the execution though for safety reasons.

Also, read [this interesting article](http://www.codemag.com/Article/0211081).

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the solutions provided?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [project Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/roslyn). Specialy the [Scripting document](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=263982) should set you on your way.

The code is bit too large to include here.